# Does Box throw an "Upload" Webhook notification for files uploaded via email?

Tags: box-api, webhooks, box

I have an application setup, for which I created an "Uploaded" webhook notification.  It works fine when I upload via drag-and-drop or via Box sync, or other API enabled process, however webhooks are not working when files are uploaded to a folder via email.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the API that Box is in the process of fixing. You should normally get a WebHook notification when files are uploaded via email.